# React D3 Tree Chart Improper Rerendering

Tags: d3.js, reactjs

I started integrating React with D3 where I use React for the DOM and D3 for the math. My use case is creating a Tree Chart where the children are collapsible.

Since I'm using React for rendering the DOM, I am trying to use `setState` to trigger a rerendering for the "collapsed" children nodes, but I am encountering some problems.

**1. It does not properly orient the nodes and paths**

**2. When I "expand" the child nodes they are placed in the wrong place**

This is the initial state of the tree. Everything looks fine

[image: Initial State]

Then I click on **Level2: A** and it collapses its children but the nodes and paths are out of place

[image: Collapsed Children]

Then when I collapse **Top Level** while **Level2: A** is collapsed and expand it I get the following

[image]

Here is a link to my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNQqoQ. If anyone has any insights it would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: your code pen does not wrk

Comment: @Cyril it should be working now. Please let me know if you have any thoughts thanks

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score -2):

Just add a couple of \u00A0 (backslash uA00A0) to the text in the children object to insert space at the start of the text

Comment: @panw has no problems with the space, the problem is rendering of the lines.